# No style from turborepo "external" package component imported in NextJS page

Tags: next.js, sass, vite, css-modules, turborepo

I have a series of small atomic packages that I want to be able to publishing and versioning independently, all within a monorepo using TurboRepo.

When these components were used as "internal" components, there was no issue.

However, when I tried to perform builds, I discovered that I couldn't get any CSS styles applied to these components when they were imported and used in my Next.js application (/apps/web).

For example, the Button package contains a single file named `Button.tsx` and a file named `Button.module.scss`.

```js
import styles from './Button.module.scss';

const Button = forwardRef<HTMLButtonElement, ButtonProps>(
  (
    {
      className,
      ...restProps
    },
    ref
  ) => {
    return (
      <button className={styles.base} ref={ref} {...restProps}>
         ...
      </button>
    );
  }
);
```

My `vite.config.js` looks like :

```js
import path from 'path';
import react from '@vitejs/plugin-react';
import { defineConfig } from 'vite';
import dts from 'vite-plugin-dts';

export default defineConfig({
  build: {
    minify: 'terser',
    lib: {
      formats: ['es', 'cjs'],
      entry: path.resolve(__dirname, 'src/index.ts'),
      name: 'Button',
      fileName: format => `button.${format}.js`,
    },
    rollupOptions: {
      // externalize deps that shouldn't be bundled
      // into your library
      external: ['react', 'react-dom'],
      output: {
        exports: 'named',
        sourcemap: true,
        format: 'es',
        preserveModules: true,
      },
      treeshake: true,
    },
  },
  plugins: [
    react(),
    dts({
      copyDtsFiles: true,
      exclude: ['**/node_modules'],
      insertTypesEntry: true,
    }),
  ],
});
```

The package.json :

```json
  "name": "@company/components__button",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "types": "./dist/index.d.ts",
  "exports": {
    ".": {
      "import": "./dist/button.es.js",
      "require": "./dist/button.cjs.js"
    }
  },
  "files": ["dist/**"],
```

[Here is a partial view of the output dist files](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GvveE.png).

Then, I import the package in my Next app (apps/web) like this :

```
"@company/components__button": "workspace:*",
```

Now, I can import it, but** no style is applied** at runtime !

However, If I inspect the DOM, I can see the class on the button DOM node:

```html
<button class="_base_3rp5a_4" type="submit">create an account</button>
```

Upon inspecting the network tab, there is a GET request fetching the page's CSS. However, the payload only contains the CSS defined at the Next.js application level and used on this same page but none of the styles included in the imported package...

Shouldn't it also include the CSS of the button imported from my package?

Does Next.js is struggling to reconcile dynamic classes with their associated styles at runtime. Am I approaching this incorrectly? Have I missed something in the configuration?

I would like the style associated with the imported package to be applied correctly.

I followed this guide : https://turbo.build/repo/docs/handbook/publishing-packages/bundling

**Edit finale solution :**

- I have created an additional package called `@company/components__css`, which includes a script enabling the retrieval of the `style.css` derived from the `build` folder of each component package (`@company/component__button`).
- In the `package.json` of the new css package, I add the list of components as dependencies. This is done so that TurboRepo adheres to the build order as follows :

1. First, the components packages are built, and CSS files are
   generated within their `dist` folder.
2. Only after that, the css package builds its own `index.css` file and removes `styles.css` from the components packages. Each component package operates autonomously. The removal of style files occurs only in context of monorepo (They are useless in the final build).

- To conclude, I add the css package dependency to Next.js application and import the style file from the `globals.scss` file, like so:
  `@import url('@company/components__css');`.

Finally, the reconciliation process proceeds seamlessly, the style is successfully fetched on the browser side, and consequently, becomes active.

You can find an example of the finale solution [here](https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/turborepo-template-forked-gt5m2t).

Comment: Do you have `scss` installed through `npm add -D sass`?

Comment: Yes of course but even with full .css file, the result is the same =)

Comment: Just posted an answer. I think that's your issue. Can you verify?

Comment: Yes Robin I'll try to do a codesandbox with minimal stuff to reproduce

Comment: @RobinThomas sorry for the delay. I created a sandbox [here](https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/turborepo-template-forked-rkqhd7).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you are bundling your UI library through `esbuild`, there shall be couple of files generated by `esbuild` in `dist` directory.

1. `index.js`
2. `index.js.map` (only if you enable sourcemap)
3. `style.css` (this is very important)

The issue here is that, you need to import that `style.css` in the Next.js app which uses the above UI library by,

```
import '<path to the style.css>';
```

Which is why even though you have the CSS classes in your HTML elements (from the `index.js` part of your UI library), no styles are applied (because those CSS classes don't exist in your DOM)

Comment: Yes, that's what I thought as well. However, conceptually, it bothers me to have to import a style file for each component I'm going to use...

I assumed that the style was "self-hosted" by the package.

Architecturally, I'm not sure what would be the most suitable approach. Do you have any ideas for an integration that is as loosely coupled as possible in a Next.js app?

Comment: @ShakurOo You don't need to import the css in all component files. You just need to import it once globally. Since you are using Nest.js, just import it in the root `layout.tsx` file.

Comment: If I import 3 different packages:

@company/components__button
@company/components__checkbox
@company/components__radio

Each of them will generate a style.css per package. So, will I have to import each style file into the layout, right?

Comment: No, there will be 1 style.css, which contains the css styles of all your `*.module.scss` files. So you need to import that single `style.css` once.

Comment: Okay, but each package is independent. So, at build time, I would need to find a way to create a "shared" style.css (meaning it contains the styles of all the components).

Or, should I create a package in my monorepo that only contains that? A CSS package?

I'm trying to find the best approach to make it as decoupled as possible from the consumer apps.

Comment: Even if you use a monorepo, you shall be still releasing the packages separately, right?

Comment: You can merge all the `style.css` together into one big `style.css`. Can use basic terminal commands for this.

Comment: Thank you, @RobinThomas. I've edited my original post, and you can find an example of the solution I've implemented.

Comment: I have not enough reputation to doing this sry